# How was the Xbox One password verification compromised?

Tags: passwords

So, we have this article:

http://www.engadget.com/2014/04/04/xbox-live-five-year-old-hacker/

Apparently, using nothing but spaces the local account (with an obviously saved password... I hope) was compromised. I am guessing that the password was TRIMMED before comparison and the dad had a password of merely spaces to begin with. Although, for a dad who is a "security researcher" this is seems awfully naive.

So, what does Security.SE think? Is there an affirmative source that confirms how this exploit works?

Answer (score 1):

The consensus seems to be that the Xbone trims terminal whitespace from entered passwords.
When the kid enters a password of just spaces, trimming whitespace results in a blank password.

So, the kid has both entered a blank password and entered a non-blank password. The empty password error handling routine chokes on this strange state of affairs and hijinks ensue.

Comment: Note that this bug is exploitable whatever the local password is, so the dad could have had a very strong password.

Comment: So the password passes a !empty test, and errors out on the password comparison because it's handled as a null value?

Comment: Yes, it seems likely that they test for !empty first, then trim the spaces.